# Update Route URL in PCF

Tags: dns, root, cloud-foundry, pcfdev

I'm new to PCF,
I just deployed my first application Pivotal Apps Manager,

I want the route to include a specific domain name,
Is there a way to update the route or to do a forward

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can map additional routes to an application that is deployed on Cloud Foundry with the `cf map-route` command. You can also unmap routes with the `cf unmap-route` command. If you want to change a route, you'd map the new route and unmap the old route. Order is important there so that the app is always accessible by at least one of the two routes.

For Pivotal's Apps Manager, you wouldn't really want to remove the old route. That's going to be set up in a specific way. You should be able to map additional routes to it, although I've never seen someone do that. Typically you'd just pick the route you want to use when you install PCF, or change your system route through Ops Manager.

Hope that helps!